# Running php file from command prompt and taking input

Tags: php, command-line

I have a php file named test.php.In that file I have to take two inputs which are number and message.I wish to execute this php file from command prompt.The problem is that after executing the php file it should ask me for inputs but it isn't doing that.My code is below

```
echo "ENTER  YOUR NUMBER";
$num = $_GET["number"];
echo "Enter your message";
$msg = $_GET["message"];
echo $num;
echo $msg;
```

Can someone help me with it?

My test.php file now contains the following code

```
echo "ENTER  YOUR NUMBER";
$num = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter your message";
$msg = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$post['num'] = $num;
$post['msg'] = $msg;



$url = 'http://172.16.1.223/source%20codes/wc.php';

$fields = array(
'num'=>urlencode($post["num"]),
'msg'=>urlencode($post["msg"])

 );

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
 $response = curl_exec($ch)
```

I am trying to access another file wc.php which is on another computer through ip address and using curl.Problem is that I am not understanding in wc.php file is the input taking format is correct or not.wc.php file contains the following code

```
$num=trim(fgets(STDIN));
$msg=trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo $num;
echo $msg;
```

I just want to pass the variables from test.php to wc.php

Comment: $_GET is http GET arguments; cli has nothing to do with http; either use $argc/$argv for command line arguments, or read from stdin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this:

```
 $input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
```

fgets takes input from STDIN and waits for a linebreak.
The trim function makes sure you don't have that line break at the end.

So to add this in your example:

```
echo "ENTER  YOUR NUMBER";
$num = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo "Enter your message";
$msg = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo $num;
echo $msg;
```

Comment: I have edited my post.But I'm facing another problem now.can you please help me out?

Comment: Here is a tutorial on how to send a POST request using CURL in PHP
https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post

Comment: Thanks a lot .It worked

Answer (score 0):

When working on the command line, you won't be able to use the superglobals ($_GET, $_REQUEST, etc.) like you can when using PHP on a website. You will want to pass the values in on the command line like this:

```
php -f myfile.php /number:"40" /message:"this is great"
```

You can then access the command line arguments with $argv.

Comment: Except OP has written a question and answer script.